# What's the best practice for using bundler, git, and jRuby gems with maven?

Tags: ruby, maven, rubygems, jruby, bundler

I'm working with jRuby and Rails for a while, but I don't have the feeling that I've found the holy grail for this:
I'm doing a lot of gems which are wrappers for actual java libs and I ask myself what the best option is for packaging those gems.
Is it a good idea to package them as "native gems", letting the jars being packaged when the gem is installed?
Is there a way to install the jars in the .m2 dir, letting bundler AND maven to what they can do best at the same time?

Best,

Tobias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, there is an easy way to install java libraries as gem:

```
gem install mvn:<groupId>:<artifactId>
```

Which should solve some of the problems.
Unfortunately, bundler does not seem to support them.

See
http://blog.mkristian.tk/2011/03/rubygems-maven-support.html

and

http://blog.mkristian.tk/2011/09/jruby-and-rubygems-and-javaclassloader.html

Also, switching to Buildr as build tool instead of mvn makes things easier.

Answer (score 1):

RubyGems Maven support **removed since jruby 1.7**

see this [RubyGems maven support has been removed in JRuby 1.7](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JRUBY-5691?focusedCommentId=310613&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-310613)

So, that won't work with jruby 1.7:

```
gem install mvn:<groupId>:<artifactId>
```

Using **jbundler** instead, refer to https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler