# Writing JRuby code that depends on gems and Maven projects

Tags: java, maven, jar, jruby

While a [similar question was asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871115/whats-the-best-practice-for-using-bundler-git-and-jruby-gems-with-maven) more than half a year ago, I'm wondering what the best way to write JRuby code that's depending on gems but also depending on Maven projects. Bundler seems to be the standard Maven like tool for the Ruby community, and I'd prefer to use that, but it looks like [bundler won't be supporting Maven dependencies](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/pull/1683).

Is `gem install mvn:<groupId>:<artifactId>` the only real solution? Would I just put that into a Rakefile? Do people then do all their gem installations with rake instead of bundler? Does anyone have other suggestions of approaching this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found my answer in [jbundler](https://github.com/mkristian/jbundler). With jbundler you define a `Mvnfile`, which looks similar to a `Gemfile`, and put your Maven dependencies there.

```
repository 'http://your-local-repo-here/'
jar 'groupId:artifactId', '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
...
```

jbundler even works with locally installed (in your .m2/repository) jars, letting you integrate with your work-in-progress Java project.

Since it integrates with Bundler, there's no need to use another tool to pull down your Maven dependencies. Just `bundle install; bundle exec something.rb`. Strangly, the Maven dependency resolution happens at `bundle exec` time and not `bundle install`, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 0):

So I was the one who wrote this and did run into some resistance as you can tell :-). Here is the blog post that describes it in more detail:
http://hokiesuns.blogspot.com/2012/02/bundler-maven-for-your-jruby-projects.html

If this helps you, then please post back indicating as such or if you think jbundler works then that can be a good solution too (I haven't looked at it in depth but it looks interesting) and glad that my work inspired someone else!

Comment: I actually ended up getting jbundler to work for me. It also works with locally installed jars.